# Cant return a string from user input in function

Tags: c, string, function, pointers

I'm trying to return a string from user input in a function but apparently it doesnt work. I got the output Name: PE but thats not what I entered when using fgets.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *userData();

int main() {

    char *name;
    userData();

    printf("\nName: %s", name);

}

const char *userData() {
    char *name;
    //INPUT FROM USER
    //NAME
    printf("\nEnter your name                 : ");
    fgets(name, 100, stdin);
    return name;

}
```

Comment: Turn on compiler warnings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has two main issues:

#### 1.

`name` in `main()` is just a pointer.

Where do you want to store the string into?

You need to either create `name` as an array of `char` or when you use `name` as pointer allocate memory dynamically via a memory-management function such as `malloc()` where the pointer point to.

#### 2.

How do you pass the pointer from `main()` to the caller? The actual parameter list of `userData` is empty, means nothing is passed.

You need to place `char *name;` in `userData` in the parameter list:

```
char *userData (char* name) {
```

and call `userData` like:

```
userData(name);
```

Note: This `name` now specifies the identifier of the pointer/buffer in `main()`, not the pointer in `userData()`.The fact that the pointer/buffer in the caller `main()`, as well as the pointer in `userData()` have the same name is a bad coincidence to showcase the example. But I think you will understand how it works.

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUFLEN 20

char * userData (char* name, size_t len);

int main (void) {

    char* name = malloc (sizeof(char) * BUFLEN);
    if (!name)
    {
        fputs("Memory allocation for name failed!", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    if (!userData(name, sizeof(char) * BUFLEN))
    {
        fputs("Error at string input!", stderr);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("\nName: %s", name);

}

char * userData (char *name, size_t len) {

    printf("\nEnter your name: ");

    if (!fgets(name, len, stdin))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    return name;
}
```

---

Side Notes:

- The return type of `userData` do not need to be `const` qualified. It has no effect. The function returns a pointer to `char`. The `const`ness has no effect as it has no influence upon whether the returned address value is accessed in the caller or not.
- First, In C, it is not possible to pass or return strings to or from functions *by value*.

  Second, There is no type called "*string*" in C. Strings are stored in modifiable or non-modifiable arrays of `char`s.

  Thus, saying "returning a string" is in two contexts incorrect. Rather you pass or return a *reference* to the arrays containing strings by using pointers.
- Update or swap your compiler. He is your helping hand detecting syntax errors in your code. For example GCC or Clang is to note.
- If you have a proper compiler, never ignore compiler warnings.

Comment: thank you, this helped me a lot. now I know how to return string. It's very difficult for me to understand pointers.

Comment: @MUFAMIN Delete the wording "return string" out of your mind. It is incorrect or even plain wrong. You do not return nor pass strings in C by value. You always pass or return pointers to buffers.

Comment: alright, understood. Looks like that's how C works, it's always passing pointers.

Comment: can you explain why the return type do not need to be const?

Comment: @MUFAMIN Because the buffer the pointer `name` is pointing is not `const`. In fact, in `userData` you modify it by writing a string to it. `const` would only be useful if `name` would point to a buffer which shouldn't be modifiable after its initialization or a string literal which is stored in read-only memory.

Comment: But even then it would not make sense to only qualify the returned pointer with `const`. The `const`antness of the returned pointer does not has an influence upon how the returned adress value is accessed in the caller.

Comment: @MUFAMIN I recommend you to download and read this book: https://kremlin.cc/k&r.pdf

Comment: that book is very helpful. Thank you very much and I'm gonna read it and expand my knowledge in C.

Answer (score 1):

The value returned from userData isn't assigned to anything in your main function. You're returning *name from the function, but you haven't told main what to do with that value it gets back. That name variable isn't shared between the functions unless you make it global, if that's what you were relying on.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `name` is a local variable in the function `userData()` and its scope is limited to that function only, since the two variables are different, you won't get the result you are expecting.

Also, you should allocate memory to the char*.